# Magento 2 find observe that fill the table sales_order_item

Tags: magento2, event-observer, table

I want to add data in the table `sales_order_item`, but for that i need to know what **Observer** fill this table. If someone know ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento `sales_order_item` table is related with `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item` .Below this event can be use at  2.1 vesion.

```
sales_order_item_save_before
sales_order_item_save_commit_after
sales_order_item_save_after
sales_order_item_delete_before
sales_order_item_delete_after
```

But from  2.2 Magento , is deprecated on  `save(), load(),delete()`  at Model class .

> Previously data is fetch  via `DB->resource model > Model  class`

New

> From ,magento 2.2 using, service contact,so  `DB->resource model >
>   Reposity class`

So, you can to track any changes in sales_order_item then suggestion to use the plugin on below class on below method

> Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item:save()
>   Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item:delete()
>   Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item:hasDataChanged()